# How can I remove hibernate core jar from build path

Tags: spring, eclipse, maven

I didn't add any hibernate related maven dependency but still ,jar coming in maven dependency folder ,it creates issue how can I remove it , thanks

Comment: Is hibernate core jar taking too much space? Or is it conflicting with other dependency?

Comment: @Popeye it's conflicts with other dependency,.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that it is a transitive dependency. Use maven dependency plugin and see from where you are getting hibernate-core jar.  https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/resolving-conflicts-using-the-dependency-tree.html

Then you can remove the parent jar if not in use or keep hibernate-core if that is not creating any problem. Depends on use case and your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You can exclude the transitive dependency see [Dependency Exclusions](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html#dependency-exclusions), of course you should identify the dependecies that brings hibernate.

Also look at how scope can affect transitive dependencies, see [Dependency Scope](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#dependency-scope)